# NaN Values in a float field in MSSQL Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, floating-point, nan

I am working on an old database I inherited from my predecessors.

In it, some float fields contains NaN where there should be a null.

The following SQL doesn't work because it doesn't recognize NaN.

```
UPDATE xxx SET column= null WHERE column=NaN
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE xxx SET column= null WHERE IsNumeric(column)=0
```

Then run your select again.