# Updating the NaN value in a DataBase

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Old database in which there is a table containing columns(**dataType REAL**) with **NaN( Not a Number)** values. Now if I query on these tables then I am getting errors. So to update these I tried the following query:

```
UPDATE Table SET column = 0 WHERE IsNumeric(column)=0
```

But even this query failed throwing error

> "returned invalid data for column ".

If the **datatype of the column is varchar then I could have easily updated.** But the Column is **REAL** so I am not able to update the table. Help me I am really stuck with this issue for two days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NaN values to NULL, or NaN to 0 in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237784/convert-nan-values-to-null-or-nan-to-0-in-sql)

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450618/nan-values-in-a-float-field-in-mssql-database

Comment: @Joey I looked at that but in that link the datatype of the column is varchar. Which is not my case.

Comment: @DavidBrabant I tried that query (I have even mentioned it in the question) but this is also not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution, by converting that column's value to string then I am able to update it.

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column = CASE
               when charindex('NaN', UPPER(Column)) > 0 then 0
               ELSE Column
             END
```

Here, I am looking for the charindex of 'NaN' since when I do CONVERT(varchar(1000), Column) the data NaN in that column became `-#@NaN`. 
So I am looking for that value in that column after converting to string. Hope this helps for others.

Sorry I don't have the old server version. I just have its backup.

**New Server Version**: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)   Apr  2 2010 15:53:02   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Interestingly, your new server is older than the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how exactly (database versions and hotfixes) you got into this situation, the following statement, issued in your database, will probably help you.

```
DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY
```

If this does not help, drop all indexes and constraints on the column and issue

```
UPDATE Table SET column = 0 WHERE IsNumeric(column)=0
```

again.  Then recreate the indexes or constraints.

Comment: This is an old DB from which i need to migrate to new DB. The first one "DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY" did not work. Even it has thrown error and terminated at the columns where there are NaN values.

Comment: Please send the output `SELECT @@VERSION` of both the old and new database servers, as well as the error message from `DBCC`.

Comment: Or, at your peril, go to single user mode and issue `dbcc checkdb (0, repair_allow_data_loss) with data_purity`

Comment: I got the solution, by converting that column's value to string then I am able to update it.

UPDATE Table
SET Column =  CASE when charindex('NaN', UPPER(Column)) > 0 then 0 ELSE Column END

Here, I am looking for the charindex of 'NaN' since when I do CONVERT(varchar(1000), Column) the data NaN in that column became -#@NaN. So I am looking for that value in that column after converting to string. Hope this helps for others.

Comment: @Amarnath - thanks for the comment.  You may want to rework it into a separate answer for the benefit of others.  Your (old and new) server version info may still add considerable value if you know it.